# long double 2d dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, double, dynamic-arrays

error: invalid types 'long double**[long double]' for array subscript

```
long double** make2darray(long int V)

{

    long double **array2,i;
    array2 = (long double**) malloc (V*sizeof(long double*));
    for(i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
        array2[i] = (long double*) malloc (V*sizeof(long double));
    }
return array2;

}
```

however, if i change the data type to long int, it works perfectly? Dont understand what is wrong with making a 2d dynamic long double array this way?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++? Also why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Also, your array index must be an integral type, so make `i` a `long int` to match `V`. (this is what the error message is telling you).

Comment: You write ***the** data type* - I guess you are not aware of what *you* are doing here. In C++, it's mostly considered bad style to declare variables before its initialisation. Especially for `for` loops you should consider to declare the index variable `i` in the narrowest scope possible: `for(int i=0;i<V;i++)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indices in arrays must always have an integral type, you need to change your declaration to:

```
long double **array2;
size_t i;
```

---

C11 standard (N1570)

> 6.5.2.1 **Array subscripting (Contraints)**
>
> 1. One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other
>      expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.

---

Also in C++ it is better to use `std::vector` or `std::array` for variable or constant length arrays respectively

Comment: +1 `Indices in arrays must always have an integral type`. I didn't try this before, surprising! Is this also true for any ancient version of C?

Comment: @Wolf I can't speak for ancient C, however modern C11 standard explicitly states _One of the expressions shall have type `pointer to complete object type`, the other
expression shall have integer type, and the result has type `type`._

Comment: C standard is so fuzzy. "One of the expressions...." It allows so strange statements like 2[array2].

Answer (score 2):

See the line

```
long double **array2,i;
```

Your variable `i` have type long double. floating point variables cannot be used for array subscript.

use this code

```
long double **array2;
size_t i;
```